# for each loop with user defined class objects in vba

Tags: class, excel, vba

The code is here and you get a Run-time error '424' Object required on the first line of the for each statement

```
Public Sub test()

Dim a As clsTest
Dim dic As Dictionary
Dim tmpObj As clsTest
Set dic = New Dictionary
Set a = New clsTest
dic.Add "1", a
dic.Add "2", New clsTest
dic.Add "3", New clsTest

For Each tmpObj In dic.Items '--<< error: Run-time error '424' Object required
  Debug.Print tmpObj.i
Next tmpObj

Stop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

you have two choices:. Declare the variable as a variant:

```
Dim tmpObj As Variant

For Each tmpObj In dic.Items

  Debug.Print tmpObj.i

Next tmpObj
```

Or iterate over the collection:

```
Dim tmpObj As clsTest

For i = 0 To dic.Count - 1

    Set tmpObj = dic.Items(i)

    Debug.Print tmpObj.i

Next i
```

Comment: Yes I've been using the variant option, but it loses intellisense, so I have to keep on changing the type from variant to clsTest when developing and back when running.

Comment: updated my code. tmpObj can be strongly typed to your custom class in this way and you have intellisense on values.

Answer (score 2):

Three options

1)

```
Dim tmpObj As Variant

For Each tmpObj In dic.Items

  Debug.Print tmpObj.i

Next tmpObj
```

2)

```
for i = 0 to dic.Count - 1
    set tmpObj = dic.Items(i)
   ...
```

3)

```
Public Sub test()

Dim a As clsTest
Dim dic As Dictionary
Dim vTmpObj As Variant
Dim tmpObj As clsTest
Set dic = New Dictionary
Set a = New clsTest
dic.Add "1", a
dic.Add "2", New clsTest
dic.Add "3", New clsTest

For Each vTmpObj In dic.Items
  Set tmpObj = vTmpObj
  Debug.Print tmpObj.i
Next vTmpObj
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Dictionary.Items()` is a variant array so `For Each` needs to have `tmpObj` as a `Variant`.

An alternative using a typed `tmpObj` is:

```
for i = 0 to dic.Count - 1
    set tmpObj = dic.Items(i)
    ...
```

Comment: It would be more usable if it returned an array of the object. Yes I had been using variant. I just thought I'd ask.